# knitr updated from 1.2 to 1.4 error: Quitting from lines

Tags: r, knitr

I recently updated knitr to 1.4, and since then my .Rnw files don't compile.
The document is rich (7 chapters, included with child="").
Now, in the recent knitr version I get an error message:

```
    Quitting from lines 131-792 (/DATEN/anna/tex/CoSta/chapter1.Rnw) 
    Quitting from lines 817-826 (/DATEN/anna/tex/CoSta/chapter1.Rnw) 
    Fehler in if (eval) { : 
    Argument kann nicht als logischer Wert interpretiert werden
```

(the last two lines mean that knitr is looking for a logical and it cannot find it.
At those lines 131 and 817 two figures end. Compiling these sniplets separately will work.
I have no idea how to resolve this problem.
Thank's in advance for any hints that allow to resolve my issue.

Here is the sessionInfo()

```
    R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

    locale:
      [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
      [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
      [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
      [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
      [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
      [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

      attached base packages:
      [1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
      [8] base     

      other attached packages:
      [1] knitr_1.4

      loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
      [1] compiler_2.15.1 digest_0.6.3    evaluate_0.4.7  formatR_0.9    
      [5] stringr_0.6.2   tcltk_2.15.1
```

Following the suggestions of Hui, I run each chapter separately with 
         knit("chapter1.Rnw")
and so on. No error message occurs, and separate tex files are created. To provide more information I display part of the code.
There is a main document in which several options are set

```
     <<options-setting,echo=FALSE>>=
     showthis <- FALSE
     evalthis <- FALSE
     evalchapter <- TRUE
     opts_chunk$set(comment=NA, fig.width=6, fig.height=4)
     @
```

The each chapter is used via child  chunks, e.g. chapter1 is called from

```
     <<child-chapter1, child='chapter1.Rnw', eval=evalchapter>>=
     @
```

The error message which appears when knitting the main Rnw file was given above.
The related Figure environment is as follows

```
     \begin{figure}[ht]
       \centering
      <<wuerfel-simulation,echo=showthis,fig.height=5>>=
      data.sample6 <- sample(1:6,repl=TRUE,100)
      table(data.sample6)
      barplot(table(data.sample6)/100,col=5,main="Haeufigkeiten beim Wuerfeln")
      @ 
      \caption{Visualisierung beim W"urfeln. 100 Versuche.}
      \label{fig:muent-vis}
      \end{figure}
```

This is not very advanced, but the error is still as it was given before.
The quitting from lines concerns a long text, from 131 (end of first chunk)  to line 792 (beginning of the followup chunk), which is

```
       << zeiten, echo=showthis,eval=evalthis>>=
       zeiten <- c(17,16,20,24,22,15,21,15,17,22)
       max(zeiten)
       mean(zeiten)
       zeiten[4] <- 18; zeiten
       mean(zeiten)
       sum(zeiten > 20)
       @
```

Is there a problem with correctly closing a chunk?

I now located the error and I provide a short piece of code with reproducible error message.It concerns conditional evaluation of child processes involving Sexpr:

The main file is the following

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    <<options-setting,echo=FALSE>>=
    evalchapter <- TRUE
    @
    <<test,child="test-child.Rnw", eval=evalchapter>>=
    @ 
    \end{document}
```

The related child file 'test-child.Rnw' is

```
     <<no-sexpr>>=
     t <- 2:4
     @ 
     text \Sexpr{(t <- 2:4)}
```

knitting this 'as is' gives the error message from above. Removing the Sexpr in the child everything works nicely.
But, everything also works nicely, if I remove the conditioning in the call of the child file, i.e., without 'eval=evalchapter'

Since I use Sexpr quite often I would like to have a solution to this problem. As I mentioned earlier, there were no problems up to knitR Version 1.2.

Comment: I posed the problem above. Let me make the following comment: If I insert the child files in the main document then the error disappears. So, the above problem is a problem with using child documents.

Comment: that sounds hard to diagnose; the first step you can go is to run `library(knitr); knit('Chapter1.Rnw')` in an interactive R session, and when the error occurs, run `traceback()` and paste the output here

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Knitting each chapter separately the error message does not show. Separate .tex files are generated succesfully.

Comment: How about `knit('main.Rnw')` and `traceback()`?

Comment: I already updated the question a few days ago, buut without leaving a comment. So, above there is a 'minimal' Rnw file with child, and  which reproduces the error. It is about Sexpr in conditional child files

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce the problem now; I think it is a bug, and I'll fix it. Thanks a lot for providing a reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a change in knitr 1.3 and mentioned in the [NEWS](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> added an argument `options` to `knit_child()` to set global chunk options for child documents; if a parent chunk calls a child document (via the `child` option), the chunk options of the parent chunk will be used as global options for the child document, e.g. for `<<foo, child='bar.Rnw', fig.path='figure/foo-'>>=`, the figure path prefix will be `figure/foo-` in `bar.Rnw`; see [How to avoid figure filenames in child calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17514055/559676) for an application

And this caused a bug for inline R code. In your case, the chunk option `eval=evalchapter` was not evaluated when it is used for evaluating inline code. I have fixed the bug in the [development version v1.4.5 on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Now, the above code is 'knitr'ed correctly, almost. For some reason no math environment is put around the numbers, such that the tex code is incorrect. This can be seen when replacing `\Sexpr{(t <- 2:4)}` in the test-child by more advanced  `\Sexpr{2* pnorm(-(2:4))}`. In this case the output is expanded into ...`6.3342\times 10^{-5}`, and the tex-compiler stops! I hope that you can fix this.

Comment: I think that I now have to put `$ \times $`around each `\Sexpr`, is that correct? Before, this was done without further notice.

Comment: @user2694363 thanks for the report! the new problem has been solved in knitr 1.4.7 on Github